# how do I select numeric value by a pattern in SQL

Tags: sql

let's say I have a table called transaction and it looks like this

```
ID   Price
--- ----------- 
706         117.94       
707         151.60       
708         185.29       
719         117.94       
711         195.85
```

If Price column's type were varchar, then I could select entries by part of Price values.

For example, if I did:

```
 select * from transaction where Price like '%51%'
```

and I would get

707         151.60

However the Price column's type is numeric. How can I select entries by part of a numeric value?

Comment: [What?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82906/1)

Comment: @Szymon no one said anything about [SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63596/2)

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  As @Alexander has pointed out, your query is perfectly valid in MySQL even if the column type were numeric.

Comment: Right, that's actually valid in SQL Server as well...

Comment: I bet this wasn't actually tried :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82906/1)
[SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63596/2)
[Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/985a9/1)
[SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/985a9/1)

Everyone of them supports `LIKE` on numbers. 
It appears to be PostgreSQL you are using. With PostgreSQL we actually need to change datatype:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction1 WHERE CAST(Price AS text) LIKE '%51%';
```

[PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/985a9/2)